# Running Scrapy in Spyder / Anaconda - spider works / CrawlSpider doesn't

Tags: python, scrapy

I've just started using Scrapy. I was able to successfully write and run a scrapy.Spider but there was issues along the way, so I started looking into CrawlSpider.

Unfortunately, when I want to run CrawlSpider using Spyder, the script starts and finishes without an exception and without having scraped anything. Not sure why that happens.

Following script works, but throws exceptions for some of the pages, which I wasn't able to fix. Also, since there are no inherent rules, the first batch of links aren't filtered and hence try scraping links that link to files like PDF.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import re

class ScraperWithLimit(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ScraperWithLimit"
    allowed_domains = ['wordperfect.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.wordperfect.com/en/'
    ]
    
    custom_settings = {
        'DEPTH_LIMIT': 5
    }
    
    def parse(self, response):
        #for next_page in response.css('a'):
        for next_page in response.selector.xpath('//a[not(contains(@href, "#")) and not(contains(@href, "mailto"))and not(contains(@href, "javascript")) and string-length(normalize-space(@href)) > 0]'):
            if next_page is not None:
                m = re.search(r"""(?i)\.(?:mng|pct|bmp|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|pst|psp|tif|tiff|ai|drw|dxf|eps|ps|svg|mp3|wma|ogg|wav|ra|aac|mid|au|aiff|3gp|asf|asx|avi|mov|mp4|mpg|qt|rm|swf|wmv|m4a|m4v|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|pps|doc|docx|odt|ods|odg|odp|css|pdf|exe|bin|rss|zip|rar)$""", next_page.get())
                if m == None:
                    yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
        
        body_text_list_raw = response.selector.xpath('//body//text()[not(parent::script) and not(parent::noscript) and string-length(normalize-space(.)) > 0]').getall()
        body_text_list = [re.sub(r"\s\s+", " ", re.sub(r"(?:\\(?:r|n|t|f|v))+", "", i)).strip() for i in body_text_list_raw]
            
        body_text_full = ' '.join(body_text_list)
        
        obj = {"url": response.request.url}
        obj['output'] = {"body_text_list": body_text_list,
                         "body_text_full": body_text_full}
        yield obj

process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
    "FEEDS": {
        "items.json": {"format": "json"},
    },
})

process.crawl(ScraperWithLimit)
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

When I run the same code using CrawlSpider, it initiates, writes a few lines of log output and then finishes, without doing anything. I have no idea why:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import re
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'crawler'
    allowed_domains = ['wordperfect.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.wordperfect.com/en/']
    
    custom_settings = {
        'DEPTH_LIMIT': 5
    }

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(deny=('(?:#|^mailto|javascript)'), deny_extensions=()), callback='parse_item', follow=True)
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        body_text_list_raw = response.selector.xpath('//body//text()[not(parent::script) and not(parent::noscript) and string-length(normalize-space(.)) > 0]').getall()
        body_text_list = [re.sub(r"\s\s+", " ", re.sub(r"(?:\\(?:r|n|t|f|v))+", "", i)).strip() for i in body_text_list_raw]
            
        body_text_full = ' '.join(body_text_list)
        
        obj = {"url": response.request.url}
        obj['output'] = {"body_text_list": body_text_list,
                         "body_text_full": body_text_full}
        return obj
            
process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
    "FEEDS": {
        "items.json": {"format": "json"},
    },
})

process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

The output:

```
2020-07-10 07:00:25 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.2.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2020-07-10 07:00:25 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.4.1.0, libxml2 2.9.9, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020), cryptography 2.8, Platform Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
2020-07-10 07:00:25 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2020-07-10 07:00:25 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{}
2020-07-10 07:00:25 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: /password/ (not sure what this is...)
2020-07-10 07:00:25 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
```

Comment: You are overriding `parse`. You should use a different callback method when using CrawlSpider. See https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/781

Comment: @Gallaecio - That didn't fix the issue. I updated the code from 'parse' to 'parse_item' (see updated main post) but experiencing the same thing.

Comment: The log you’ve posted seem incomplete. It does not even include the crawling of the start URL. Is that all you get?

Comment: @Gallaecio yes it is.

Comment: Your log should also include a traceback which indicates the problem with your code: `rules` is not iterable. You need to understand how `(foo)` is different from `(foo,)` in Python. Alternatively, you could use a list instead of a tuple for `rules`.